# Unexpected behaviour of r11 register

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

Today I've written the assembly code that is used for printing the debug string in this pattern:

"rax = 1      rbx = -2     rcx = 3      rdx = -4     rsi = 5      rdi = -6      r8 = 7       r9 = -8     r10 = 9      r11 = 0      r12 = 11     r13 = -12    r14 = 13     r15 = -14"

But to test this code I just wrote it repeatedly like this:

```
    call _getDebugString
    mov r9, debugString
    call _printTextSafe
    call _getDebugString
    mov r9, debugString
    call _printTextSafe
    mov r11, -24
    call _getDebugString
    mov r9, debugString
    call _printTextSafe
    call _getDebugString
    mov r9, debugString
    call _printTextSafe
    call _exit
```

In my subroutine _getDebugString I push all used registers to safe them. But there's problem with register r11. After a subroutine completed its always 582.

You can check this out, here's the respond:

rax = 1      rbx = -2     rcx = 3      rdx = -4     rsi = 5      rdi = -6      r8 = 7       r9 = -8     r10 = 9      r11 = 0      r12 = 11     r13 = -12    r14 = 13     r15 = -14

rax = 1      rbx = -2     rcx = 3      rdx = -4     rsi = 5      rdi = -6      r8 = 7       r9 = 4202678r10 = 9      r11 = 582    r12 = 11     r13 = -12    r14 = 13     r15 = -14

rax = 1      rbx = -2     rcx = 3      rdx = -4     rsi = 5      rdi = -6      r8 = 7       r9 = 4202678r10 = 9      r11 = -24    r12 = 11     r13 = -12    r14 = 13     r15 = -14

rax = 1      rbx = -2     rcx = 3      rdx = -4     rsi = 5      rdi = -6      r8 = 7       r9 = 4202678r10 = 9      r11 = 582    r12 = 11     r13 = -12    r14 = 13     r15 = -14

Insights what would it be? Maybe I don't know smth about this register and there's a mystery about number 582?

Comment: Let's see the code for `_printTextSafe` and `_getDebugString`.  Make this a [mcve].  One special thing about r11 is that's it's overwritten by the `syscall` instruction, so if some part of your code makes a system call without saving and restoring r11, that could explain it.

Comment: Specifically, `syscall` overwrites r11 with the contents of `rflags`, and 582 = 0x246 is a plausible value for `rflags`.  The bits set are bit 9 (IF), bit 6 (ZF), bit 2 (PF), and bit 1 (reserved, always 1).

Comment: Oh shit. Right! In print function I push everything but that. You're genius! Thanks!

Comment: Now it works properly!